# Different App Versions for Different Clients as OEM Partner

Tags: appexchange, custom, app, oem

Is it possible to provide a customized version of your app to each of your clients as an OEM partner?

For example, you have a base version of your app but one client wanted some change, so can you release that change to just the selected client?

Answer (score 1):

Such an approach does not make sense and strictly you have one package per listing available through the app exchange. While you can have different package versions, 1GP only supports a single upgrade sequence with minor changes (no new components) in patch versions.

While 2GP allows more branching of versions, maintaining many separate variants of the package will quickly become unfeasible.

Adding new listings per customer, even when based on the same core code base, will lead to multiple security review requirements with the associated annual costs.

The better approach is a single package with feature based licensing. Here you have features that can be made available via licensing to specific customers and not others.

Note, however, that I would always recommend avoiding adding customer specific features in a product. Instead, provide the basic framework for realising such features in the product, but with the customer specific elements built on top of this core, either in an extension package or directly on the customer's subscriber org.